# Count of specific decimal values in a column in SSRS Table

Tags: reporting-services, count, expression, ssrs-expression

I am trying to get a sum of people of a specific age. AgeInYears is a Decimal.

I have tried a sum and get 0 every time

```
=SUM(IIF( Fields!AgeInYears.Value = 15, 1, 0 ) )
```

If I do a count I get 68 which is still incorrect

```
=Count(IIF( Fields!AgeInYears.Value = 15, 1, 0 ) )
```

I'm not sure if I am comparing to a decimal correctly. When I use my query in SQL, then use a pivot table on the data I'm able to find the answer as 47 (I'm much better with excel than SSRS). But in SSRS I can only get a 0 or 68 Value.

EDIT
I am calculating the AgeInYears myself in my Query via

```
cast(cast(datediff(month, invl.ChildDateOfBirth, fp.enddate) as decimal) / 12 as decimal) as AgeInYears
```

could this be related?

Comment: Your first code should work, but you could be right with the decimal compare, try `=SUM(IIF( Fields!AgeInYears.Value = CDec(15), 1, 0 ) )`

Comment: Thanks, that still gives me a 0 when using the sum, and 68 when doing a count. Also the Value does not change even if i change 15 to any other number.

Comment: Hmmm maybe try converting it to an int in SQL i.e. `convert(int, AgeInYears) AgeInYears` just to be 100% sure, then use `CInt(15)` in your expression above.

Comment: AgeInYears is a value I calculate myself, I have added how I do that. Maybe my SQL is wrong here?

Comment: What results is that returning in your raw SQL query?

Comment: It returns the correct age as a decimal.

Comment: I have joined the chat thanks

Comment: I can't think of anything else - sorry - that should work as far as I can tell, but SSRS does have some odd quirks which can take a bit of trial and error to work around.

Comment: why not do a case statement in your sql and then show the sum in SSRS.. something like case when age = 15 then 1 else 0 end as age_fifteen. On the report side, you simply go = sum(fields!age_fifteen.Value)

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. I have decided to do a group over all AgeInYears and limit my Query to only pull from the correct range of ages. (I only needed count of each age between 14 and 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve whatever issue that SSRS was giving me when I attempted to count the ages.

Instead I have updated my query to

```
Select
    cast(cast(datediff(month, invl.ChildDateOfBirth, fp.enddate) as decimal) / 12 as decimal) as AgeInYears
From Table
Where
    cast(cast(datediff(month, invl.ChildDateOfBirth, fp.enddate) as decimal) / 12 as decimal) > 13 
and 
    cast(cast(datediff(month, invl.ChildDateOfBirth, fp.enddate) as decimal) / 12 as decimal) as AgeInYears < 19
```

This ensures my data only contains ages that I want ( between 14-18.
Then in the SSRS table I created a row group over AgeInYears and did a simple

```
=Count(Fields!AgeInYears.Value)
```

in the text box to get the correct count for each Age.